# Why does Chrome have TTL -1000 in the DNS Cache?

Tags: google-chrome, dns, proxy

[image: Chrome DNS Screen]

I am working in a corporate environment, using Chrome.  I am investigating some weird behavior, which may or may not turn out to be DNS-based.

If I navigate to:

chrome://net-internals/hostresolver#dns

I get the above image, which shows TTL values -1000.

What does this mean?  I understand what a *negative* TTL usually means, but even for the non-expired row (which is a proxy, and is resolved) it has a value of -1000.

Anyone know how this works?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome DNS cache has negative TTL and expires just after a minute](https://superuser.com/questions/1368838/chrome-dns-cache-has-negative-ttl-and-expires-just-after-a-minute)